# Не ставится MySQL 5.5 под Debian

Tags: debian, mysql

Есть Debian, в репозиториях лежит только MySQL 5.1. Качаю .deb пакет с официального сайта MySQL. Далее после команды (установлены права на пакет 777):

```
root@box-test:~# dpkg -i /root/mysql-server-5.5.deb
```

Ошибка:

> `dpkg: не удалось обработать параметр /root/mysql-server-5.5.deb (--install):нет доступа к архиву: Нет такого файла или каталогаПри обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки: /root/mysql-server-5.5.deb`

Захожу через MC внутрь пакета, запускаю нажатием Enter скрипт INSTALL (777), выдаёт через минутного раздумья:

```
root@box-test:~# /usr/lib/mc/extfs.d/deb run /root/mysql-5.5.deb INSTALL
```

> `Installing /root/mysql-5.5.deb(Чтение базы данных ... на данный момент установлено 24808 файлов и каталогов.)Подготовка к замене пакета mysql 5.5.18 (используется файл /root/mysql-5.5.deb)                                                                               ...Распаковывается замена для пакета mysql ...Настраивается пакет mysql (5.5.18) ...`

И всё... ни установленного MySQL, ни сработок по командам типа `apt-get install mysql-server-5.5.18`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, способ поставить MySQL версии 5.5 без сборки его из исходников. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: @EgODiEz, а чем не устраивает сборка из исходников? Могу расписать подробно, как собрать из исходников - это довольно просто.

Comment: Если честно ни разу ничего не собирал под *nix, поэтому ищу быстрый способ, т.к. это необходимо для работы. Для интереса и дома можно покопаться, если Вы говорите что времени занимает немного сборка, то прошу скинуть ссылку на адекватный ман. Но всё-таки хотелось бы получить ссылочку на рабочий репозиторий, как говориться нужно быть проще =) Я не ленивый, у меня просто сейчас небольшой завал на работе, поэтому приходится ставить приоритеты, экономить время...

Comment: По опыту могу сказать, что ветка 5.5 не очень стабильна. Если нет критической необходимости именно в этой ветке, то лучше используйте 5.1.

Comment: Если все-таки решите ставить из deb пакета, то подключите репозиторий dotdeb. С ним проблем нет http://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решено, правда и пришлось поплясать, так как во всех предлагаемых мануалах и решениях на форумах есть куча недочётов и ни один из способов не сработал на 100%. Пришлось собирать из нескольких и додумывать самому. Способ актуален для версий **Debian 6.0.3** и **MySQL-server-5.5.19**:

Итак, для сборки нам понадобятся пакеты *build-essential*, *cmake*, *libncurses5-dev*, *chkconfig* Если их нет, устанавливаем:

```
apt-get install build-essential cmake libncurses5-dev chkconfig
```

Далее качаем исходники:

```
cd /tmpwget http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/mysql-5.5.19.tar.gz/from/http:/mysql.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.mysql.com/
```

Здесь он может сохранить архив в **index.htm**. Переименуем в **mysql-5.5.19.tar.gz** и распакуем:

```
tar -xf mysql-5.5.19.tar.gzcd mysql-5.5.19
```

Cоздаём заранее пользователя и группу для мускула:

```
groupadd mysqluseradd -r -g mysql mysql
```

Конфигурируем, компилируем, устанавливаем:

```
cmake .makemake install
```

Задаём права:

```
cd /usr/local/mysqlchown -R mysql .chgrp -R mysql .scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql/chown -R root .chown -R mysql data
```

Копируем конфигурационый файл в папку **/etc**:

```
cp support-files/my-medium.cnf /etc/my.cnf
```

Устанавливаем сервис, назначаем права, добавляем в автозапуск и запускаем:

```
cp support-files/mysql.server /etc/init.d/mysqldchmod +x /etc/init.d/mysqldchkconfig --levels 235 mysqld onservice mysqld start
```

Если запуск прошел успешно, устанавливаем пароль пользователя **root**:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'password'
```

*Готово, надеюсь кому-нибудь помогут мои часовые пляски =)*

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте все-таки собрать из исходного кода. Это займет на 10 минут больше.

1. Необходимо скачать тарбол с официального сайта.
2. Распакуйте архив во временную директорию:

   tar -xf <имя_скачанного_архива>.tar.gz -C /имя/директории/куда/распаковывать
3. Теперь переходим в директорию, содержащию файлы исходного кода.
4. Конфигурируем (скорее всего опций по умолчанию достаточно), поэтому просто:

   ./configure
5. Теперь собираем (компилируем во временной директории), опять же просто:

   make
6. Теперь устанавливаем (переносим собранный код в рабочую директорию):

   make install
7. Проверяем работу:

   /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe & -u root
8. На этом сборка и установка окончена.

**P.S.** Вопреки распространенному мнению - сборка из исходников это не пререгатива "домашних исследователей". На моей работе тех. площадка из чуть более 100 серверов. ПО устанавливается именно из исходников. Никаких проблем с дальнейшим обслуживанием и сопровождением нет.

Comment: Кофиг мускуля производится cmake . Ув. bsdmacs у Вас устаревшие сведения, прошу впредь не пускать по ложному следу. На данный момент самая актуальная настройка приведена ниже, она довольно таки по многим пунктам отличается от вашего мануала.

Answer (score 0):

Поставить MySQL версии 5.5 без сборки его из исходников поможет подключение стороннего репозитория Dotdeb.По адресу http://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/ находятся подробные инструкции как это сделать.